# AJAX Symfony Form + embedded form = error not returned in correct sub form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a **symfony 4.2** form via AJAX with embedded sub-form that is used as a custom group.

The problem is that my `imgLinks` which is a part of the embedded form `group_pictures` does not return its error as a part of the `group_picture` bu as a lone error without any group.

The field is being validated and the error is returned as expected EXCEPT not assigned to the correct group.

In the symfony profiler `Form tab`, I can see the error related to the field but it does not display the error as part of the group like shown in the screenshot below

[image]

[image: no error added]

This is a very odd behaviour as all my other fields return errors in their respective groups.

In the profiler `post parameter` we can see that it is submitted with the correct group:

[image]

So here is the entity field:

```
 /**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="img_links", type="simple_array")
 *
 * @AcmeAssert\ImageLinks
 */
private $imgLinks;
```

Changing my custom `Assert` for another bundled with symfony results in the same behaviour so my custom constraint is not the culprit

The Form Type

```
$builder->add(
     $builder->create('group_pictures', FormType::class, array('inherit_data' => true))
       ->add('imgLinks', CollectionType::class, array(
            'label' => false,
            'entry_type' => TextType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
       ))
 );
```

My controller function to collect errors and return them to my AJAX

```
    private function getErrorMessages($form)
{
    $errors = array();

    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
        $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
    }

    foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
        if (!$child->isValid()) {
            $errors[$child->getName()] = $this->getErrorMessages($child);
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

in the error collector above if I insert code to dump the `group picture` child like this:

```
if( $child->getName() == 'group_pictures'){
     dump($child);
 }
```

I see that there is no error assigned to it `-errors: []`

Then the errors returned to the browser (console screenshot) as you can see the error is assigned the key `0` instead of `group_picture`

[image: browser error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getErrorMessages
```

Method first assign the error as ordered /index => value/ and then for every child form the error is assigned as unordered /key => value/

This part for me is a bit odd

this is what i'm using

public function

```
function getErrors(FormInterface $form)
        {
            $this->childErrors($form);

            foreach ($form->all() as $key => $child) {
                if ($child instanceof FormInterface) {
                    $this->childErrors($child, true);
                }
            }

            return $this->errors;
    }
```

And this is the childErrors method

```
private function childErrors(FormInterface $form, $recursive = false)
{
    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {
        $message = $this->translator->trans($error->getMessage(), [], 'validators');
        $this->errors[] = $message;
    }

    if ($form->count() && $recursive) {
        foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
            $this->childErrors($child, $recursive);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
yes, it is the `error_bubbling` options.

The collection type entries should be set **error_bubbling** to **true** /it is by default **false** and the collection type itself is set to true, so it will need to be disabled otherwise the error will bubble up to the main form.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried your method and had to modify `$this->errors[] = $message;`  to `$this->errors[$form->getName()] = $message;` weird enough I can see that my `imgLinks` is assigned to a `field name` called `new_bike` so not even assigned the correct field name which is `imgLinks`

Comment: Im beginning to think that the javascript is to blame somehow because `new_bike` comes from the prototype `ul` but since the form `post` parameter shows correct assignment I am not sure

Comment: You need the javascript ? let me know what you need

Comment: I added the javascript part to the question

Comment: actually the array with form errors is correct. because you have a **CollectionType** in your form and you validate each item from the collection the error is assigned with his name in the **$this->errors** array, but because the form name of each item in the collection type is it's index that's why you have ordered array

Comment: thanks for the clarification; so no error there then; that brings me back to no idea :) I have been searching the web for hours now. I also assigned the `key` from `$form->all() as $key => $child` to the error message only to find that there is no key at all for the `imgLinks` error so the problem comes from the validation but I am still not sure if this is caused by a bad prototype

Comment: if you want your errors to map to **imgLinks** you will need to use it like this:
`
->add('imgLinks', CollectionType::class, [
                    'label' => false,
                    'entry_type' => TextType::class,
                    'error_bubbling' => false,
                    'entry_options' => [
                        'required' => false,
                        'constraints' => new NotBlank(),
                        'error_bubbling' => true,
                    ],
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                ])
`

Comment: Alexander genius ! casually bringing the solution in a comment lol It was the `error bubbling` I guess ? but I am struggling to find out why because you have it to `false` then `true`. Please modify your answer so I can accept it. Thanks :)